# Select across multiple tables in Entity Framework resulting in a generic IQueryable?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, generics

I have a situation where I create a method, which takes in a list of requirements (specifications).

These specifications is specified i my `PriceSpecification` object, which has a list of nullable properties, which can work as requirements (various enum or id's).

I work with Entity Framework, and my specifications can be properties from three different tables.

I want to create a temp object, using LINQ, as seen in the code. Then depending on the specified properties in the specification, I want to find the right object and make C# objects using a factory pattern.

Usually I do the following, when I work with a single table:

```
public List<Customer> GetCustomerBySpecification(CustomerSpecification specification)
    {
        IQueryable<DbCustomers> dbCustomers = repository.DbCustomers;

        if (specification.Id > 0)
        {
            dbCustomers = dbCustomers.Where(c => c.Id == specification.Id);
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(specification.Email))
        {
            dbCustomers = dbCustomers.Where(c => c.Email == specification.Email);
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(specification.ResetPasswordKey))
        {
            dbCustomers = dbCustomers.Where(c => c.ResetPasswordKey == specification.ResetPasswordKey);
        }

        return customerFactory.Create(dbCustomers.OrderBy(c=>c.Id).Skip(specification.Skip).Take(specification.Take).ToList());
    }
```

However, now I work with three tables. I have tried to make the code which you can see below. The problem is the where statements give me the error: `Cannot apply operator '==' to operands of ype 'int' and 'LetterColor', candidates are: [...]` .

From the test_obj.Where() I just need to be able to get ID properties out from the three tables joined together.

```
 public Price GetPriceBySpecification(PriceSpecification specification)
        {
            var test_obj = from d in repository.DbPricing
                join d1 in repository.DbOfficeProducts on d.OfficeProductId equals d1.Id
                join d2 in repository.DbOfficeProductDetails on d1.ProductDetailsId equals d2.Id
                select new
                {
                    PricingId = d.Id,
                    LetterColor = d2.LetterColor,
                    LetterPaperWeight = d2.LetterPaperWeight
                };


            if (specification.LetterColor.HasValue)
            {
                test_obj = test_obj.Where(c => c.LetterColor == specification.LetterColor.Value);
            }
            if (specification.LetterPaperWeight.HasValue)
            {
                test_obj = test_obj.Where(c => c.LetterPaperWeight == specification.LetterPaperWeight.Value);
            }

            // Convert found data into a C# object using a Factory class

            // Return awesome stuff

            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

So my question is:

How do I modify my `GetPriceBySpecification(PriceSpecification specification)` method, so I can use where statements with properties from all three tables, and get the ID's out afterwards? :)

EDIT:

Added some more code:

```
public class PriceSpecification:Specifications
    {
        public LetterColor? LetterColor { get; set; }
        public LetterPaperWeight? LetterPaperWeight { get; set; }
        public LetterProcessing? LetterProcessing { get; set; }
        public LetterSize? LetterSize { get; set; }
        public LetterType? LetterType { get; set; }
    }
```

These types are types such as this:

```
public enum LetterColor
{
    BlackWhite=0,
    Color=1
}
```

Comment: Without knowing the types of LetterColor and LetterPaperWeight, it's going to be hard to help. If possible, please update the question with the source models.

Comment: @ScottCorbett Thanks, added more code:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public Price GetPriceBySpecification(PriceSpecification specification)
    {
        var test_obj = from d in repository.DbPricing
            join d1 in repository.DbOfficeProducts on d.OfficeProductId equals d1.Id
            join d2 in repository.DbOfficeProductDetails on d1.ProductDetailsId equals d2.Id
            //select new <- anonymous object 
            select new Price
            {
                PricingId = d.Id,
                LetterColor = d2.LetterColor,
                LetterPaperWeight = d2.LetterPaperWeight
            };


        if (specification.LetterColor.HasValue)
        {
            test_obj = test_obj.Where(c => c.LetterColor == specification.LetterColor.Value);
        }
        if (specification.LetterPaperWeight.HasValue)
        {
            test_obj = test_obj.Where(c => c.LetterPaperWeight == specification.LetterPaperWeight.Value);
        }

        // Convert found data into a C# object using a Factory class

        // Return awesome stuff

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Comment: You solved a big problem of mine - thanks a lot Lee :)